# Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipelines for the Azure SQL Always Encrypted database Issues

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, dacpac

During the Setup of the Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipelines for the Azure SQL Always Encrypted database,

1. Example :- Table1 consists of the 5 columns, out of the 5 column's Column1 and Column2 were encrypted
2. Always Enabled setting in Connection string
3. Dacpac file successfully created without any issues and able to view the Table1
4. Observed the issue with while inserting data in to Table1 by using transaction data
5. Error Message : Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables
6. Same code is working fine if execute this dacpac file manually in SSMS studio
7. Displaying error if use execute the dapac through SSDT or CI/CD Pipelines

Please let me know your thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually CI/CD pipeline with Dacpac working together is complex with Always encrypted enabled.Please check if the below points can narrow down the issue.

- Usually the certificate for the Column Master Key is stored in the
  client machine, not on the SQL server machine. If that is the case,
  you are not able to insert data into the table with an Always
  Encrypted column,Do the  Master Key configuration .

(Hope you already knew but just for your info mismatch error in ssms can be solved [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-query-columns-ads?view=sql-server-ver15))

According to [permissions-for-publishing-a-dac-package-if-always-encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-dacpac?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions-for-publishing-a-dac-package-if-always-encrypted-is-set-up)

> To publish DAC package if Always Encrypted is set up in the DACPAC
> or/and in the target database, you might need some or all of the below
> permissions, depending on the differences between the schema in the
> DACPAC and the target database schema.
>
> ALTER ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY, ALTER ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY, VIEW ANY
> COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION, VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY
> DEFINITION

- Also note that Azure SQL is a PaaS Service which means it receives
  update transparently and relatively often with a new compatibility
  level. Try updating SSDT version . Always Encrypted is supported in
  all editions of SQL Server Database V12.
- Always Encrypted uses two types of cryptographic keys: column
  encryption keys (CEKs) and column master keys (CMKs). see [developing
  databases using always encrypted](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/developing-databases-using-always-encrypted-with-sql-server-data/ba-p/386108#:%7E:text=We%20are%20excited%20to%20announce%20that%20SQL%20Server,never%20revealed%20in%20plaintext%20to%20the%20database%20system.)
- Please do variable declaration and value assignment are performed on
  the same line.

  Example:

  DECLARE @OPERATION_ID int = 4

  DECLARE @PARAMETER_NAME varchar(100) = 'xyz'

Try to store the value to be inserted in a variable or result and store in the application and then insert the data from the result set into SQL Server.

Also see

1. [azure-encryption-server-side-client-side-azure-key-vault](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-azure-encryption-server-side-client-side-azure-key-vault)
2. [create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted.md)
3. [ci-with-a-sql-always-encrypted-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619527/ci-with-a-sql-always-encrypted-column)